# Calculating lunch

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image: Help calculating lunch]

I need the formula I already have to also include if lunch (30) is in E12. It also needs to calculate if 0 is placed in the E column if they haven't taken a lunch.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are 0 and 30 the only values you'll ever allow in column E?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
=(F12-D12+(D12>F12))*24-(E12/60)
```

After it does the current calculation, it removes the effect of lunch (or no lunch).

Notice that you have to multiply your current calculation by 24. That is because the time values are the decimal part of a date/time. In other words, from 0 to 1.00. So eight hours is 0.33, not 8.00.

That's why directly subtracting "30" from it won't work. and since after multiplying by 24 you have full hours, not (essentially) the percentage of a day that has passed, you  cannot just subtract it from that either.

However, you CAN divide it by 60 to convert the minutes to hours and subtract that. Which is what the formula does.

Notice that you want to subtract 0 if they enter a 0, so you can divide EITHER entry they should be making by 60. After all, if 0, it yields 0 and has no effect on the result.

By placing it outside the current calculation, you get two benefits. You divide by the clearer notion of 60 minutes to get hours, instead of converting to the fraction of the day it represents by also dividing by 24:  `E12/60/24`... and then multiplying it back by 24 as the formula ends! Small savings but, you know... and also, easier to read and understand.

You could consider also wrapping everything in an `IF()` that checks whether the E12 entry is acceptable or not and outputs "Mistake with lunch" or something similar if they enter something unfortunate. Anything from a typo to perhaps "0.5" or even something more (less!) helpful on their parts. I mention it because this entry will be very much like dates:  everyone will find three of their own ways to screw it up for you even though you put a helpful example in the header cell. It just won't matter. A test like this could go a long way to keeping some of that from happening. Some. Better than none though!